# Best way to use LESS CSS

Tags: css, less

I have just started using LESS CSS and it is great so far.

I do have a question or I am looking for a recommendation on the best way to use it.

I have been testing with the Mac Compiler and the client-side JS version.

I am sure there is some overhead to running it client-side and the Mac compiler works but its a bit slow because I keep having to run it.

Can anyone give me the pros and cons of each and if you have had more success doing it a certain way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a mac and have been using [StaticMatic](http://staticmatic.rubyforge.org/).

If you're not afraid of the Terminal, you can quickly start new projects which generates some source files in HAML and SASS. Then you can run WebBrick (localhost:3000) to see you generated code on the fly.

When you're all done StaticMatic has a built in feature to "build" your site --> will generate HTML and CSS.

Hope this helps.